# INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s) doing `where git`

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have git installed under `C:\Program Files\Git\` I do the following from a `setupenv.bat`:

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Git\bin";%PATH%
```

So doing the following I can see it:

```
echo %PATH%
```

The following will then work:

```
git --version
>git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

But this won't:

```
where git
>INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)
```

Comment: I would assume it is because you have used the double-quotes, which should not have been there. `Path` locations are delimited with semi-colons, so you should not be double-quoting the `git` location. Try changing `set PATH="C:\Program Files\Git\bin";%PATH%`, to , `Set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%`, or more correctly `Set "Path=%Path%C:\Program Files\Git\bin;"`. instead. Additionally, don't use lazy typing and allow the parser to search for, and append, each extension listed under `%PATHEXT%`, to your filename, use `git.exe`, it will always run a fraction quicker.

Comment: Indeed this is the answer, I am happy to confirm that it solves then issue. Can you please make it a proper answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, is most likely that you have surrounded your location string with double-quotes.

The locations listed within the `%Path%` string value content are delimited with semi-colons, for that reason your intended addition to that value content should not be double-quoted.

If you take a look at the existing `%Path%` content, by typing `Path` at the Command Prompt, and pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you'll note the absence of double-quotes, and most likely that there are paths which include space characters.

The solution therefore is to change your `set` command from:

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Git\bin";%PATH%
```

to:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%
```

However, I will add that the recommended syntax for the `Set` command is:

```
Set "VariableName=Variable Value"
```

So you should really write it thus:

```sh
Set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%"
```

It should be noted too that the locations listed within the value of `Path` are searched in order, which means that you should consider carefully whether your new location should be located and therefore searched first, or last. The precedence could be important depending upon what else is being done within that script.
As the `Path` value string should already be semi-colon terminated, you could just as easily locate it at the end:

```sh
Set "Path=%Path%C:\Program Files\Git\bin;"
```

Also note that there is already an environment variable available for the normal `\Program Files\` directory, so you could additionally incorporate that instead:

```sh
Set "Path=%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin;%Path%"
```

Comment: This is interesting! Usually quotation marks *should* not harm (sometimes they may even be required, think of paths containing semicolons on their own), but of course it depends of the program that handles the `%PATH%` variable…

Comment: @aschipfl, yeah, the `%path%`  variable uses semicolon as delimiter. It is two sided though as the path variable with double quotes will work 100% for executables, but the search functions like `where` does not like the double quotes.

Comment: I wasn't too suprised @aschipfl, because I remember seeing a similar issue previously with the `%~$Path:` expansion in a `For` loop. I would, if my memory serves also expect that, `@For %%G In ("git.exe") Do @Echo %%~$Path:G` would fail too. I suppose that anyone stupid enough to use semi-colon is their file or directory names, should expect issues.

Comment: Is it better to use `"SET "PATH=..."` or use the internal `PATH` command?

Comment: I would not say that 'better' is quatifiable in this case @lit, but IMO, not using the `Set` command is more likely to confuse a reader of the code. Saying that, although getting a little off topic here, I'd be much happier if I could use `PATHEXT ;` instead of `Set "PATHEXT="`